# How do I manually set the max value for the Y axis in my pandas boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, axes

I'm looking at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) official Pandas documentation, which says I can specify an "object of class matplotlib.axes.Axes" when creating my boxplot.

How do I format this boxplot axis object so that I can manually set the maximum Y axis value?

I've seen questions and answers on here relating to changing the Y axis *after* the boxplot is created, but those have not worked for me and I'd like to set the Y axis max at the time of the boxplot's creation.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd    
prices= pd.read_csv('..\priceData.csv')
boxplot = prices.boxplot(column=['price'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the `Axes` returned by `boxplot` and use:

```
xmin, xmax = [-5, 5]
ymin, ymax = [-5, 5]

boxplot = prices.boxplot(column=['price'])
boxplot.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
boxplot.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

`boxplot` from the documentation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4),
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

[image]

After `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`:

[image]

Comment: I followed these instructions by creating the boxplot, setting the ylim, and then trying to show the boxplot again, but ylim just returns the bounds I specified in parentheses and the boxplot visual's y axis didn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you execute your code? Spyder, Pycharm, VSCode, other?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook

Comment: `boxplot.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])` `boxplot.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])` must be in the same cell as the plot call. `%matplotlib inline` is not required in current jupyter.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Putting them in the same cell solved the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

- The correct way is to use the `ylim` and `xlim` parameters.
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) shows the full set of parameters available in [`pandas.DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html).
- When using Jupyter, `ax.` methods must be in the same cell as the plot call `ax = df.plot(...)`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])

ax = df.plot(kind='box', ylim=(-5, 5))
```

[image]

- Use the `yticks` and `xticks` parameters to specify ticks.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='box', ylim=(-5, 5), yticks=range(-5, 6))

# or only use the following without ylim
ax = df.plot(kind='box', yticks=range(-5, 6))
```

[image]